# Visual Studio Code Black Screen issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, raspbian

When I launch VS Code after installation, I get black screen. I tried to reinstall it, but without a result and I also tried to start it with «--disable-gpu» argument, no result too. Is there any possible solution for this?
[Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg9Bw.jpg)

[Also «--status» argument.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSg02.jpg)

---

I use Raspberry Pi 3 on Raspbian and code-oss 1.32.0 ARM (by headmelted)

Answer (score 0):

you've probably figured it out so far, but I'll answer in case anyone else visits this thread.

All you need to do is downgrade code-oss.

```
sudo apt-get install code-oss=1.29.0-1539702286
```